# Set an image in a button

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone application.
I have a view with a button in which I would like to set an image.

I found a lot of solution through Internet but it still not work.

Actually, it works when I put an URL from the Internet. The image is well displayed on the button but when it's from my resources folder, no image is loaded.

Here is my XAML code to do that :

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ShowSearchFilterCommand}" Height="100" Width="100">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="resources/SearchFilterIcon.png" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I set the build action of my image to "Content". The designer display the image so I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: you have to set the correct path to your image source. /FolderName/ImageName.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the correct path to your image source as in a way `/FolderName/ImageName.png`.

If the images are placed inside nested folders set like this

> Source="/FirstFolderName/SecondFolderName/.../ImageName.Extnsion"

Comment: I was looking for the answer since one hour ! Thanks you a lot !
I just missed a simple slash before my first folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            <Button>
                <ItemsControl>
                    <Image Source="/Assets/images/ImageName.png"></Image>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Button>
```